# XSLT 1.0: Insert elements to an Aarray

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've a XML similar to the following, i want to read the `<LocationID>` and map the relevant ID with the correspondent name and store it with comma separated.
I'm done with the corresponding name mapping using `for-each`, but i am unable to store the both values in an array(to later concatenate with comma) or store in a variable. How can I achieve the final part

```
<Data>
 <Mapping>
   <LocationID>001</LocationID>
   <GeoX>1.00</GeoX>
   <GeoY>2.00</GeoY>
 </Mapping>
 <Mapping>
   <LocationID>002</LocationID>
   <GeoX>56.00</GeoX>
   <GeoY>42.00</GeoY>
 <Mapping>
</Data>
```

Expected output:

```
<Location>
 <Name>ABC,XYZ</Name>
 <Cost>$1200</Cost>
</Location>
```

Existing code

```
<Location>
   <xsl:for-each select="location/type">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="LocationID='001'">
         <xsl:variable name="loc1" select="ABC"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="LocationID='002'">
         <xsl:variable name="loc2" select="XYZ"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name="loc" select="NEW"/>
      </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($loc1,$loc2,$loc)" />
    </Name>
    <Cost>
      <xsl:value-of select="cost" />
    </Cost>
</Location>
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing part of the input. Where does the Name and Cost come from? Also post you have coded so far.

Comment: Hi @Sebastien Name is the combination of LocationID, where i decode as i mentioned above. I get the name by decoding the LocationID. Now i want to concatenate that and create one attribute call <Name>, which has the Names of the locations. Cost it just another attribute, i can get that straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<Data>
 <Mapping>
   <LocationID>001</LocationID>
   <GeoX>1.00</GeoX>
   <GeoY>2.00</GeoY>
 </Mapping>
 <Mapping>
   <LocationID>002</LocationID>
   <GeoX>56.00</GeoX>
   <GeoY>42.00</GeoY>
 </Mapping>
</Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <Location>
        <Name>
            <xsl:for-each select="Mapping">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="LocationID='001'">ABC</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="LocationID='002'">XYZ</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>NEW</xsl:otherwise> 
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Name>
        <Cost>
            <xsl:value-of select="some-missing-node" />
        </Cost>
    </Location>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Location>
  <Name>ABC,XYZ</Name>
  <Cost/>
</Location>
```

Comment: Hi Micheal, thank for you for the help, it indeed worked, do you give me a hint how to achieve formatting result as following "ABC","XYZ"

Comment: Hint: `<xsl:when test="LocationID='001'">"ABC"</xsl:when>`

Comment: I'm lost, i've tried <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\&quot;', '"')"/> along with your hint, i'm still unable to escape the double quotes. It looks like something like this 
`"\"ABC\",\"XYZ\""`

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question. Does this work as expected: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12fq ?

Comment: That what i originally tried before i requested a hint from you. it didn't work as i expected. it giving me something like this, please note, for the question sake i have used the XML, but in real scenario i'm using a JSON format as my output, `"Name": "ABC,XYZ"`, when i use the double quotes it's giving me something like `"\"ABC\",\"XYZ\""`.

Comment: If you want the final result to be`"ABC,XYZ"` then you do NOT want to put quotes around each value - contrary to what you show in your 1st comment. Place quotes only before and after the `xsl:for-each` block.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes my last comment is bit misleading, what i was trying to say was, in my JSON output i'm getting the output  as `"Name": "ABC,XYZ"` which i want to turn into `"Name": "ABC","XYZ"`

Comment: I don't see the part where you convert the output to JSON. And this is not a good place to solve the problem. Post a new question.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, i have been working on this for last few hours, i have opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204158/xslt-1-0-format-json-output-using-xslt-remove-defualt-quotes-in-an-json-array)