# XSLT 1.0: Format JSON output using XSLT/ Remove defualt quotes in an JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-to-json

I have a the following JSON response, that I'm getting after a XSLT transformation. The values in the `"name"` array needed to be present as `"ABC","XYZ"`

**Payload**

```
<Data>
 <Mapping>
   <LocationID>001</LocationID>
   <GeoX>1.00</GeoX>
   <GeoY>2.00</GeoY>
 </Mapping>
 <Mapping>
   <LocationID>002</LocationID>
   <GeoX>56.00</GeoX>
   <GeoY>42.00</GeoY>
 <Mapping>
</Data>
```

Current Code where the `Destination` object is implemented.

```
<xsl:template match="//Data">
   <Destination>
      <Locations>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml-multiple?&gt;</xsl:text>
            <Name>
             <jsonArray>
               <xsl:for-each select="Mapping">
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="LocationID='001'">"ABC"</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="LocationID='002'">"XYZ"</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>"NEW"</xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
               </xsl:for-each>
              </jsonArray>
            </Name>
        </Locations>
    </Destination>
</xsl:template>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Destination>
  <Locations>
    <Name>"ABC","XYZ"</Name>
  </Locations>
</Destination>
```

**Problem XML-to-JSON Output**

```
"Destination": [
    {
        "Locations": {
            "Name": [
                "\"ABC\",\"XYZ\""
            ]
        },
```

**Expected JSON Output**

```
"Destination": [
    {
        "Locations": {
            "Name": [
                "ABC","XYZ"
            ]
        },
```

This "\"ABC\",\"XYZ\"" escape characters happen when i'm converting the XML to JSON. Is there a way to overcome this.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing the input and a complete XSLT. Your current code does NOT produce the output you show.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I can't shared something similar, since i am unable to share the XSLT in whole. I understand if it's difficult, i'm using the previous payload, and i want to receive  values inside the `Name` array as `"ABC","XYZ"`. i hope this makes things clear for you

Comment: You are asking us to fix code that we cannot see. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I understand. I will close it, i was thinking if we assign the ABC, and XYZ to a variable and concatenate at the end will that way will be able to achieve  `"ABC","XYZ"`

Comment: There is no problem in generating an output of `"ABC","XYZ" ` - as I already showed: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12fq. The problem is that you have additional code that escapes the quotes. We don't know how this code works, so there is no way to tell what input it needs to produce the expected JSON, if it's at all possible, or how it needs to be modified in case it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the above code as following.

**Previous Code:**

```
<xsl:template match="//Data">
   <Destination>
      <Locations>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml-multiple?&gt;</xsl:text>
            <Name>
             <jsonArray>
               <xsl:for-each select="Mapping">
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="LocationID='001'">"ABC"</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="LocationID='002'">"XYZ"</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>"NEW"</xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:for-each>
              </jsonArray>
            </Name>
        </Locations>
    </Destination>
</xsl:template>
```

**Changed code:**

```
<xsl:template match="//Data">
   <Destination>
      <Locations>
               <xsl:for-each select="Mapping">
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="LocationID='001'"><Name>ABC</Name></xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="LocationID='002'"><Name>XYZ</Name></xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise><Name>NEW</Name></xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:for-each>
        </Locations>
    </Destination>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
"Destination": [
    {
        "Locations": {
            "Name": [
                "ABC",
                "XYZ"
            ]
        },
```